# Change default freeradius auth and acct port in CoovaChilli

Tags: openwrt, freeradius, coovachilli

So I have two freeradius / radiusdesk installations on the server.

First one is old one and uses default freeradius ports: 1812/1813 for Auth/Acct.

The second one is the new once and using ports: 10001/10002 for Auth/Acct.

The issue now is that on my router, CoovaChili is always connection to the first one ( old one ) and communicating on the ports 1812/1813. I want to change it's ports. But it doesn't seems to be working. The OS is OpenWrt.

In my `/etc/config/chilli` i have added the following lines:

```
option radiusauthport 10001
option radiusacctport 10002
```

But is is not working. CoovaChilli still sends request to the old 1812/1813 ports. I want to know how to change that so it communicates with my defined port numbers, rather than the default ones.

Looking for the configurations to fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the OpernWRT guide at https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/services/captive-portal/wireless.hotspot.coova-chilli, it seems that you need to put the *value* parameter inside double quotes.

Specifically

```
option radiusauthport "10001"
option radiusacctport "10002
```

Comment: Ok i will try that

Comment: I tried this solution and it seems to work and now even without double quotes it is working.